# Authentication for different user Laravel ( Trying to get property of non-object )

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware

Hei guys another error in authentication login, So I want to give different dashboard for different user, so example user_type = 1 it will redirect to user1/dashboard and user_type = 2 it will redirect to user2/dashboard but I got this error

> Trying to get property of non-object authentication

this is my LoginController in laravel

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials) && Auth::user()->user->user_type == 1) {
  // Authentication passed...
  return redirect('user1/dashboard');
  } else {
  Session::flash('login_error');
  return redirect('/login');
}
```

this is my middleware, I make it 2 middleware with User1Middleware and User2Middleware

```
if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->users->user_type == 1)
    {
        return $next($request);
    } else {
        return redirect('/login');
    }
```

So Users is on my database and user_type is my table name, Can you help me guys so glad if this problem can fix very soon

From the answer I edited my code to this but still got bug it redirect to user1/dashboard not redirect to user2/dashboard even I have logic for user_type = 2

```
$credentials = $request->only('email', 'password','user_type');
$credentials["is_verified"] = true;
if (Auth::attempt($credentials) && Auth::user()->user_type == 1) { 
   // Authentication passed... 
return redirect('user1/dashboard'); 
} else if( Auth::attempt($credentials) && Auth::user()->user_type == 2) { 
return redirect('user2/dashboard'); 
} else { 
Session::flash('login_error'); 
return redirect('/login'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do this:

`Auth::user()->user`

Because the first piece of code:

`Auth::user()`

Is the user. With this in mind, you can change your code to look like this:

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials) && Auth::user()->user_type == 1) {
  // Authentication passed...
  return redirect('user1/dashboard');
  } else {
  Session::flash('login_error');
  return redirect('/login');
}

if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->user_type == 1)
    {
        return $next($request);
    } else {
        return redirect('/login');
    }
```

There you go buddy!

**EDIT:** Code added to question

Your `else if` only checks if the user has a type, it does not have this piece of code:

`Auth::attempt($credentials)`

Comment: thanks but I still got bug so I add else if for user_type 2 and then it also redirect to user/dashboard
if (Auth::attempt($credentials) && Auth::user()->user_type == 1) {
  // Authentication passed...
  return redirect('user1/dashboard');
  } else if(Auth::user()->user_type == 2) {
                return redirect('user2/dashboard');
   }
else {
  Session::flash('login_error');
  return redirect('/login');
}

Comment: Could you edit that comment and add some code tags? I can't read it

Comment: still got that bug bro I edited my question to add credential code

Comment: Can you show me a screen or the code of this file: `web.php` ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi in LoginController add or replace method

```
protected function authenticated($request, $user)
    {
        if ($user->user_type == 1) {
            return redirect()->route('here you route name');
        }


        return redirect()->route('here you route name for second type of user');
    }
```

Comment: can't do this sorry